# Unique flight combination with total passengers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with flight information and I'd like to get the flight combination with the highest number of total passengers. When considering flight combinations, flights whose departure and arrival match need to be considered as one combination. Meaning, flights from Seattle to LA or LA to Seattle should be considered as one combination.

```
FlightCode   Departure   Arrival  Date          NumberOfPassengers
----------------------------------------------------------------
C10          Seattle     LA       2019-01-10    100
C11          LA          Vegas    2019-01-10    200
D12          LA          Seattle  2019-01-20    50
C12          Seattle     LA       2019-01-11    200
Z10          NYC         Chicago  2019-03-12    90
```

Expected Output

```
Departure  Arrival NumberOfPassengers
-------------------------------------
LA         Seattle 350
or 
Seattle    LA      350
```

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try below trick -

```
select top 1
    (case when departure>arrival then departure else arrival end) as Departure,
    (case when departure>arrival then arrival else departure end) as Arrival,
    sum(NumberOfPassengers) as NumberOfPassengers
from FlightTable as f
group by (case when departure>arrival then departure else arrival end),
         (case when departure>arrival then arrival else departure end)
order by sum(NumberOfPassengers) desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this almost similar way as others by combining Departure & Arrival for GROUP BY as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7774d5f174e147eb7084debf1d3f7345)

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Departure > Arrival THEN Departure +' To '+ Arrival
    ELSE Arrival +' To '+ Departure
END,
SUM(NumberOfPassengers)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN Departure > Arrival THEN Departure +' To '+ Arrival
    ELSE Arrival +' To '+ Departure
END
```

Comment: thank you! your solution does exactly I was looking for but unfortunately, I can mark only one as the answer

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `CASE` expressions to find the least and greatest city from each departure/arrival pair:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Departure < Arrival THEN Departure ELSE Arrival END AS Departure,
        CASE WHEN Departure < Arrival THEN Arrival ELSE Departure END AS Arrival,
        NumberOfPassengers
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Departure,
    Arrival,
    SUM(NumberOfPassengers) AS NumberOfPassengers
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Departure,
    Arrival;
```

Note that some databases support greatest/least scalar functions which can avoid the messy `CASE` expressions, but SQL Server does not have them.  Also, I use a CTE to turn out the departures/arrivals to avoid putting a `CASE` expression into the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: thank you! your solution does exactly I was looking for but unfortunately, I can mark only one as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),FT.Departure,FT.Arrival,SUM(FT.NumberOfPassengers)
FROM Flight_table AS FT
GROUP BY FT.Departure,
         FT.Arrival
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your correct and expected query.

```
SELECT Departure,
       Arrival,
       SUM(NumberOfPassengers) AS NumberOfPassengers
FROM flight
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN Arrival > Departure THEN Arrival
             WHEN Departure > Arrival THEN Departure
             END;
```